# BETWEEN statement within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a weird example in SQL Server. The situation is the following:
I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ID  value1  value2
60FB    14.54   46.05
7066    12.18   41.23
7072    16.18   46.65
710F    12.17   47.65
7126    13.18   49.65
713E    17.18   48.65
7141    12.19   41.33
7144    12.18   47.65
7147    19.18   49.65
7149    18.18   42.65
71A6    17.18   43.65
71AA    14.54   44.05
```

ID is char, value1 is decimal, value2 is decimal.

If I do the select statement in SQL Server:

```
SELECT ID, value1, value2 
FROM         Node
where value1 between 12.1 and 12.2
and value2 between 41.2 and 41.5
```

I get this result which is what I want to have:

```
ID  value1  value2
7066    12.18   41.23
7141    12.19   41.33
```

Now I want to pass the between parameters into the stored procedure which looks like this:

```
create procedure XYZ

@value1min decimal(2,5),
@value2min decimal(2,5),
@value1max decimal(2,5),
@value2max decimal(2,5)

AS
BEGIN

SELECT ID, value1, value2 
FROM         Node
where value1 between @value1min and @value1max
and value2 between @value2min and @value2max
```

When I run the procedure with the same parameters I get the wrong result which is:

```
ID  value1  value2
7066    12.18   41.23
710F    12.17   47.65
7141    12.19   41.33
7144    12.18   47.65
```

I think that problem is in the value1 where all values are fulfilling the condition, but the two aren't fulfilling the condition of value2 range so I don't know why 710F and 7144 are appearing in the results.

Does anyone have any answer on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What does the stored proc call look like please? What are the column datatypes?

Comment: The parameter order is suspicious, with value1 and value2 mixed. Are you sure you're passing the parameters in the right order?

Comment: Actually, that *isn't* your stored proc because decimal(2,5) fails. So how can we help you troubleshoot? -1

Comment: @Mark: Could you mean decimal(5,2) by any chance?

Comment: I did a mistake when copying the information into the question. The correct values used for the query are: @value1min= 12.1, @value1max= 12.2, @value2min= 41.2, @value2max=47.75 (I hope I did it correct this time). With sql query I get the results of two lines, with SP I get the result of 4 lines.

Comment: @Mark: so it works **as expected** then and this question is even more pointless. 47.75 is very different to 41.5: that's not even a typo. The stored proc definition is wrong. Voting to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer:

Please for goodness's sake don't simplify the question so much that

1. the problem is gone
2. the proc is not even valid syntax

Sample table

```
create table node (ID char(4), value1 decimal(10,4), value2 decimal(10,4))
insert node select
'60FB' ,14.54  , 46.05 union all select
'7066' ,12.18  , 41.23 union all select
'7072' ,16.18  , 46.65 union all select
'710F' ,12.17  , 47.65 union all select
'7126' ,13.18  , 49.65 union all select
'713E' ,17.18  , 48.65 union all select
'7141' ,12.19  , 41.33 union all select
'7144' ,12.18  , 47.65 union all select
'7147' ,19.18  , 49.65 union all select
'7149' ,18.18  , 42.65 union all select
'71A6' ,17.18  , 43.65 union all select
'71AA' ,14.54  , 44.05
GO
```

Sample proc

```
create procedure XYZ
@value1min decimal(5,2),   --- << --- note here
@value2min decimal(5,2),
@value1max decimal(5,2),
@value2max decimal(5,2)
AS
SELECT ID, value1, value2 
FROM         Node
where value1 between @value1min and @value1max
and value2 between @value2min and @value2max
GO
```

The select using fixed values, followed by two execs. Note that the 2nd and 3rd params are swapped

```
select * from node
where value1 between 12.1 and 12.2
and value2 between 41.2 and 41.5
;
exec xyz 12.1, 12.2, 41.2, 41.5
;
exec xyz 12.1, 41.2, 12.2, 41.5
```

In **every single** case, the output is

```
ID     value1    value2
7066   12.1800   41.2300
7141   12.1900   41.3300
```

Note

- `--- << --- note here` If you change the param to `decimal(2,5)`, you get *`Msg 192, Level 15, State 1, Procedure testme, Line 1. The scale must be less than or equal to the precision.`*
- if you change it to (7,5), there's no difference; numbers that fit in (5,2) will fit in (7,5).

So where is the problem again?

If I were to **guess** at all, it will be that you are passing the wrong parameters to the EXEC.

Comment: Now try to use this parameters: @value1min= 12.1, @value1max= 12.2, @value2min= 41.2, @value2max=47.75 and do it with SP and with query itself.

Comment: @Mark: then it works as expected despite your broken stored proc

Comment: @gbn, @Richard aka syberkiwi: it's working now. It was the wrong decimal setting in my table where my settings in the table were more granular (e.g.: 3,5) but in SP they were 2,5.

Comment: @Mark: decimal (3,5) is still impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You got your `DECIMAL` definitions mixed up:

```
decimal(2,5)
```

That means: I want `DECIMAL`, with a **total of 2 digits**, thereof **5 after** the decimal separator.

What you probably mean to define is:

```
decimal(7,5)
```

`DECIMAL` with a **total of 7 digits**, 5 thereof after the decimal separator (and two before it).

What type are the columns in your table??

From the [MSDN documentation for DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

> decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]
>
> Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid
>   values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.
>
> **p (precision)**
>
> **The maximum total number of decimal digits** that can be stored,
>   both to the left and to the right of
>   the decimal point. The precision must
>   be a value from 1 through the maximum
>   precision of 38. The default precision
>   is 18.
>
> **s (scale)**
>
> The **maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right
>   of the decimal point**. Scale must be a
>   value from 0 through p. Scale can be
>   specified only if precision is
>   specified. The default scale is 0;
>   therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum
>   storage sizes vary, based on the
>   precision.

Comment: It won't create the stored proc with decimal (2,5). Good call

Comment: -1 presumptious. This statement "I get the wrong result" points to the param being wrong `in the question` but not IRL. It doesn't say - The SP isn't working

Comment: @marc_s - no it won't. `create proc testme @d decimal(2,5) as select @d
` => `Msg 192, Level 15, State 1, Procedure testme, Line 1. The scale must be less than or equal to the precision.` The answer **is** looking at the wrong place, -1 stays

Comment: @marc_s: decimal(2,5) is correct based on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx For precision of 0-9 digits we need to use 5 storage bytes (in our case precision of two digits we are using 5 bytes for storage)

Comment: @Mark: Based on that link you first specify precision, which is 5 in your case, then scale, which is 2. So the correct declaration should use `decimal(5,2)`.